# C++ Pointers and C-style array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Long time java programmer here, new to C++. I have been working with C-style "traditional" arrays (similar to arrays in java). I understand in C++ we can create a simple array as follows:

`Person people[3];`

The contents of this array is essentially uninitialized junk values. When I print out the contents of each element in the array, I (believe) am getting the memory address of each element.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){std::cout << &person[i] << std::endl;}
```

Results:

```
//Note, I get different results here when I use an enhanced for loop vs an iterator for loop. Weird.
00EFFB6C
00EFFBA8
00EFFBE4
```

Now, here is the part I have failed to get a clear explanation on. I create a pointer to one of the elements in the array. I then ask for some value *back* from that pointer. In java, I would expect to get a null pointer, but in C++, that is not happening.

Instead, I get the default value, as though this element is initialized:

```
Person* person1Ptr = &people[0];//Points to an uninitialized value
std::cout << person1Ptr->getFirstName() << std::endl;//Output: "Default First Name", expected nullptr
```

When I try to get the first name of an element using a reference, this doesn't work (presumably because the value doesn't exist).

Full paste of code: https://pastebin.com/cEadfJhr

From my research, C++ does NOT fill arrays with objects of the specified type automagically.

**How is my person1Ptr returning a value?**

Comment: typo, sorry - fixing now

Comment: In `Person people[3];` the initial state of the 3 `Person` elements depend on what `Person` is. If it is a `class` type they will be default initialized. Whether or not that means there is uninitialized data depends on how `Person` is implemented.

Comment: *"From my research, C++ does NOT fill arrays with objects of the specified type automagically."* This is incorrect. Since you are coming from a Java background, you may have the preconception that `Person` is some form of handle to an instance of `Person`. In the case of `Person people[3];` you have three actual instances of `Person` no matter what. What you may be thinking of is that C++ might not initialize those objects to a meaningful value. Whether or not that happens depends on the details of `Person`.

Comment: *"Instead, I get the default value, as though this element is initialized"* Something to know about C++, specially coming from a higher level language like Java, is that C++ has a core concept of *Undefined Behavior* that comes up a lot. Most programming or logic errors in C++ lead to Undefined Behavior. This means that the error is not guaranteed to produce an error or even behave differently from what you expect. It means that it is not possible to determine if something works or not based purely on observation. It may appear to work, by coincidence. But it may stop working for no reason.

Comment: You should share a [MCVE] including a short definition for `Person` that produces the behavior you witnessed. It is difficult to answer the question specifically without knowing more about your test.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I will add a pastebin of my .h, .cpp, & my main where I am executing this

Comment: It is site policy that you should post the code in the question directly instead of as an external link. Please make sure that it is minimal but sufficient for the question asked. The link provided in my last comment should clarify what is expected from the shared code.

Comment: `Person` is a `class` type with a default constructor, so all three elements get default constructed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh, ok. I just didn't want to put too much "mess" in the question. I will edit, and you thank you for both the guidance and the answer in the comments. If you make an official answer below based on your comment above, I will accept.

Comment: I think you are confusing values with pointers. `people[0]` definitely _exists_. Yes, it might contain garbage values if they weren't initialized by the default ctor, but it can't ever be `nullptr`, because it's not of pointer type. Only pointers can be `nullptr`, values can't.

Comment: As a general rule in C++, C style arrays should be avoided in favor of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). They are equivalent in terms of performance and avoid several traps with C arrays including decaying to pointers and passing by value. In your case, it would be `std::array<People, 3> persons;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem stems from this misconception :

> From my research, C++ does NOT fill arrays with objects of the specified type automagically.

C++ objects have value semantics. Defining a local variable of type `T` concretely creates a unique instance of that type, it is not a handle to a potential `T`. The expression `Foo f;` is conceptually equivalent to the Java expression `Foo f = new Foo();`. Additionally, value semantics means assignment usually implies a copy. The C++ expression `Foo f; Foo g = f;` is conceptually equivalent to the Java expression `Foo f = new Foo(); Foo g = f.Clone();`.

In the case of an array, defining a local variable `Foo f[3];` immediately creates three instances of `Foo` as elements of the `f` array. Your misconception may come from the fact that creating an object in C++ does not imply that it has been initialized. An object can exist in an uninitialized state. For example `int i;` create an `int` object identified by `i` but its value is indeterminate. In the case of `int i[3];` you would have an array of three `int` each with indeterminate values.

The [rules for initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) are very complicated in C++. In the case of `Person people[3];` you have an array that is [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

You are initializing an object of type `Person[3]`. According to default initialization rules :

> if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;

That means each `Person` gets its own default initialization. To see what happens, consider that `T` is `Person` :

> if T is a class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;

So each `Person`'s default constructor will be called to initialize that element. You end up with `Person people[3];` defining three default constructed `Person` objects with default initial values.

Comment: In the first part, you mean Foo f = new Foo(); Foo g = f.clone(); in java, correct? Right now, you have it listed as Foo f = new Foo(); Foo f = f.clone();
Thank you for the clarification to C++ array object initialization. It does seem odd to me, however, that C++ would generate instances for each element in the array. Object instantiation for each element in the array could potentially result in large performance overhead, no?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, that was a typo. It was means to be `Foo g = f.Clone()`, which I've corrected in the answer.

Comment: @Matthew In C++, an array of objects is a collection of objects. If you write `Foo f[3];` you tell the compiler "I want 3 `Foo` right now". If this is a performance problem, than you probably don't want to ask that and shouldn't use `Foo[3]`. If you instead want 3 *handles* to potential future instances, you can use something else. Maybe `Foo* f[3];`, `std::optional<Foo> f[3]`, `std::shared_ptr<Foo> f[3]`, `std::unique_ptr<Foo> f[3]` or any of countless other possibilities, including `std::vector<Foo> f;` which in most cases will be preferable to `Foo f[3]`.

Comment: @Matthew Each approach is suitable for a different use case. The best approach depends on what you actually want to accomplish and the context in which you want to accomplish it.